# What Theorem/Lemma is used in the proof? (Cauchy Theorem-Abstract Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

i'm studying, and tried the following exercise

> Prove that a group of order 28 has a normal subgroup of order 7.

Which i found a solution, but i don't know which theorem or how to deduce something, the proof is

*Proof:* Note that $o(G)=28=2^2\cdot 7$, therefore there exists $x\in G$ such that $o(x)=7$, by Cauchy theorem, consider $\left<x\right>$ of order $7$, we know that $\left<x\right>\leq G$, therefore we know

$$|G|=28\nmid 24=4!=[G:\left<x\right>]!$$

**then $\left<x\right>$ must contain a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$.**

Therefore, $\left<x\right>$ is the normal subgroup of order $7$ of $G$.

What i don't get, is the result in bold, is there a theorem that says, that? or how do you deduce it from there? thanks.

Comment: How does $4!$  come in?

Comment: well, that's some of the things i don't know, that's why i think, he's using a theorem or something, that says something about the factorial, i just know that the order of $[G:\left<x\right>]$ is $4$.

Comment: The usual way to prove $\langle x\rangle$ is via Sylow theorems.

Comment: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_simple_non-abelian_group_divides_factorial_of_index_of_proper_subgroup

Comment: this problem comes before the Sylow Theorems, in Topics in Algebra, so, i think it would be nice to have an alternative proof, without the Sylow Thoerems.

Comment: @GastónBurrull Thanks! that's exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to think about it. If $H\subset G$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $G$ acts on the cosets of $H$ in $G$ via the rule for $g\in G$, $aH\in G/H$:

$$g\cdot aH = gaH$$

Now, if the index of $H$ in $G$ is $n$, then there are $n$ cosets of $H$ in $G$ so the group action gives us a group homomorphism

$$\phi:G\longrightarrow S_n$$

where $S_n$ denotes the symmetric group on $n$ elements. The group homomorphism is where the $4!$ comes in in your question. If $|G|$ does not divide $|S_n| = n!$, then $\phi$ cannot be injective (the image of $G$ would give a subgroup of $S_n$ of size $|G|$). Hence the homomorphism must have a nontrivial kernel. This nontrivial kernel is the nontrivial normal subgroup you are looking for.

Comment: +1, and a comment: I could remember the result that "if $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ and $G$ has a subgroup of index $p$, then $G$ can't be simple"  but I could never remember its proof. By now, I can remember at least that it uses basically these ingredients :)

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy's theorem there is a subgroup $H$ of order $7$.

If $K$ is another subgroup of order $7$, then $H\cap K=1$ (why?).

But then $|HK|=|H|.|K|/|H\cap K|=7.7$ contradiction.

So subgroup of order $7$ is unique hence normal.